# Small sample size error using power calculation for two proportions

Tags: r, power-analysis

I am trying to use power analysis for sample size selection using the pwr library in R.

```
library(pwr)
pwr.2p2n.test(h = 0.1, n1 = 78, power = 0.8, sig.level = 0.0125)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in uniroot(function(n2) eval(p.body) - power, c(2 + 1e-10, 1e+09)) : f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

If I change the sample size (greater) or change the effect size to medium (0.4) then it'll run. Any solutions would be wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to achieve 0.8 power with *any* sample size in the second group (no matter how large), with your other constraints, e.g.

```r
library(pwr)
pfun <- function(n2) {
    pwr.2p2n.test(h = 0.1, n1 = 78, n2 = n2, sig.level = 0.0125)$power
}
pfun2 <- Vectorize(pfun)

png("ppow.png")
curve(pfun2(x), from = 100, to = 1e9, log="x")
dev.off()
```

[image: power curve saturating at 0.053]

I've "only" tried sample sizes up to 10^9, but it seems that no matter how large you make `n2`, you can't get power > 0.054 or so with this setup.  So this isn't a computational problem, it's a structural/statistical one.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I just came to same conclusion after iteratively changing the two sample sizes and seeing how high power would increase and had the same findings with pwr and the function "wp.prop" from package "WebPower".